# I have a question about the datasheet for AD8330 VGA (variable gain amplifier)

Tags: amplifier, analog

I don't have much experience reading datasheets. I was reading the datasheet for AD8330 VGA. I did not understand what the difference is between VDBS and VMAG. Can someone elaborate on that?

It's mentioned throughout the datasheet. The below picture is from page one of the datasheet. Is the idea that we can choose whether we want dB gain or regular numeric gain? And if we want to control the value for VMAG, do we just connect it to vcc?

[image]

It's explained more on page 17 of the datasheet.

[image]

The datasheet is for the AD8330 VGA. You can access the datasheet from here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8330.pdf

Thank you

Comment: yes, you can paste the link to the datasheet ... one from manufacturer's website would be preferable

Comment: So I have googled my morning papers: (1) "AD8330 Low Cost, DC to 150 MHz, Variable Gain Amplifier Product Sheet - Analog Devices":
https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8330.html,

(2) "AD8330 Low Cost, DC to 150 MHz, Variable Gain Amplifier Datasheet - Analog Devices":
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8330.pdf.. Cheers.

Comment: The datasheet says the following: (a) The basic gain function is linear-in-dB, controlled by the voltage applied to Pin ***VDBS***. The gain ranges from 0 dB to 50 dB for control voltages between 0 V and 1.5 V—a slope of 30 mV/dB. The gain linearity is typically within ±0.1 dB. 

(b) By changing the logic level on Pin ***MODE***, the gain decreases over the same range, with an opposite slope. 

(c) A second gain control port is provided at the ***VMAG*** pin and allows the user to vary the numeric gain from a factor of 0.03 to 10.

Comment: So do you think I should connect the VMAG pin to a supply voltage to get that 0.03 to 10 factor. I know VMAG is set to 500 mv by default, when it's unconnected.

Comment: For details you also need to read the figures for values. Eg, Vdbs Gain (dB) vs Vdbs (Volts): https://i.imgur.com/XHIILiG.jpeg. Similarly, for Vmag, you can read Fig 5 for details.